# Where can I find the list of reserved Haskell keywords as [String]

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm generated some haskell code (in haskell) and I need to be able to detect name which clash with haskell keyword. Is there somewhere to programmatically check if a String is an Haskell keyword ?

I could of course compile the list of them myself, but I don't like to reinvent the wheel. Moreover, if new keyword are introduced (by extensions or in new specification) I would like this list to be updated automatically.

Answer (score 8):

[hscolour uses such a simple list for its `tokenise` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hscolour-1.20.3/docs/src/Language-Haskell-HsColour-Classify.html#tokenise).

```
keywords =
  ["case","class","data","default","deriving","do","else","forall"
  ,"if","import","in","infix","infixl","infixr","instance","let","module"
  ,"newtype","of","qualified","then","type","where","_"
  ,"foreign","ccall","as","safe","unsafe"]
keyglyphs =
  ["..","::","=","\\","|","<-","->","@","~","=>","[","]"]
layoutchars =
  map (:[]) ";{}(),"
symbols =
  "!#$%&*+./<=>?@\\^|-~"
```

You can just

```
import Language.Haskell.HsColour.Classify

isKeyword :: String -> Bool
isKeyword = (== [Keyword]) . map fst . tokenise
```

Comment: I was expecting something from `GHC` itself but I guess it's better than nothing.

Comment: GHC takes more of a traditional, but less accessible approach, with its Happy/Alex parser/lexer-generator combination.

Answer (score 6):

Here it is: https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/d784bdeb62a6b11831c5235a97449ff2a86dcc52/compiler/parser/Lexer.x#L708-L765

I'm sure it is complete list, because it is what GHC lexer understands as reserved words. Another interesting list is [`reservedSymsFS`](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/compiler/parser/Lexer.x#L729) - reserved symbols.